# UINavigtionController Nib's Top Bar Black opaque not showing black on UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have created new Storyboard Project in Swift and added UINavgationController to initial UIViewController then I changed color of Navigation Bar to black of UINavigationController from storyboard, but when I run the application its showing white color navigation bar.

Please note that I do not want programmatic solution to this issue. I need solution to this issue using storyboard only.

**[UPDATE]**

this is how I did from storyboard
[image]

this is what I get in Simulator:
[image]

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: add this line in viewdidload self.navigation!.navigationBar.barTintColor! = UIColor.black

Comment: Thanks Maniganda but I have mentioned in my question that I don't need code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what have you done in the storyboard. But this is what you can do to make it work:

1. Select a navigation bar inside the navigation controller.

[image: Navigation bar selection]

2. Pick the desired style.

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Another solution would be to use appearance. Keep in mind, it will be applied to all navigation bars in the project.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
```

**UPDATE 2**

Or

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
```

**UPDATE 3**

If you really don't want to write any code, this is what you may do from the storyboard. Here `1` corresponds to `UIBarStyleBlack`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Artem Stepanenko but this is not working, I have already done this

Comment: I've just created a dummy project and it works. Are you sure you selected a navigation bar (not a navigation controller)?

Comment: I had used Embed in option to assign UINavigationController maybe thats why its not working?

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot showing what do you mean by setting an Embed option?

Comment: Its on top bar of XCode, Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation

Comment: Yes that was the issue of using Embed in, now I add manually then it worked, Thanks Artem

Comment: Do you think, you can accept the answer? Or you really want to make it work in conjunction with "Embed"?

Comment: I have voted up for this answer, but actually I had another issue I was using SlideMenuControllerSwift library, that was causing this issue, not Embed in was causing, I was wrong, now When I disable SlideMenuController then color is changed to black but when I add this library then again it turns color to white

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **Bar Tint** color to **BlackColor** and uncheck **Translucent**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using a left sliding menu library that was causing this issue. That library was overriding navigation bar that's why I was seeing white navigation.